# Is there any way,I can create website using my 32bit OS?Most softwares didn't support my laptop

Tags: web, 32-bit

I want to build a professional website, but my laptop doesn't accompanies me as it is a 32bit OS.I wish to know if there is a solution to create my project.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very broad, but if you need a starting point, consider these info.

**About the editor**: you can use anything (Notepad, Notepad++, VS Code, gedit, vim, etc.). Websites in frontend are in form of HTML/CSS/JS files with images and in backend about PHP/Node.js/etc., as textual files you can edit them with any 32-bit editor without issues.

**About the server** (hosted on your own machine), on Windows:

- As starting point, for simplicity, there is [WampServer](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) that still supports 32-bit operative systems.
- You also could try using [XAMPP 32 bit version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.2/]). It's Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin all in one. But it's outdated! I would rather consider upgrading to a 64-bit operative system, if you can.

If you are building a website for a customer, you probably want to have a **developing** and a **production** environment, so that things don't break while you are developing from your customer point of view. Development would be in local, that's why Wampserver/Xamppserver can be useful. In **production** you can use those too, but it would require a **dedicated server**. You are better off using **web hosting services** (there are free and paid plans) that gives you good uptime and 24/7 availability.

Just search for "web hosting" and you will be flooded by over 446 billion results.